# How to know if a Flex application is running on iPad or iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, apache-flex

I have a Flex application which runs on iPad, now I want the same app to run on iPhone with some modifications to the view interfaces in order to preserve their look and feel. The question is: Is it possible to tell when the app is running on iPad and when is running on iPhone to do such thing? I know that by doing this:

```
flash.system.Capabilities.version.indexOf("IOS");
```

you can know if the app is running on iOS, but you don't know which device is.

I hope you can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**edsv14**, actually you've almost got what you want :)
Just instead of *Capabilities.version* use *Capabilities.os*.
So you'll get smth. like this: "iPhone OS 5.1.1 iPod4,1" (iPod), "iPhone OS 6.0.1 iPad2,2" (iPad2), "iPhone OS 5.1.1 iPad3,3" (iPad3), "iPhone OS 4.3.3 iPhone3,1" (iPhone4) etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can distinguish the devices by screen resolution, which works quite well using the `Capabilities` class. 
For further distinction between iPad1/2 and 3 you need a little workaround, though.

Check this article: http://www.richardlord.net/blog/using-the-ipad-retina-display-with-adobe-air

Answer (score 0):

Check the screen resolution using [Capabilities.screenResolutionX](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html#screenResolutionX) and [Capabilities.screenResolutionY](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html#screenResolutionY) ?

You can do some conditional logic to figure out which iOS device you're on from there.